# Can I buy products that are made in Germany?

Tags: holocaust-shoah

Is there an accepted practice among Jews to not buy products from Germany because of the behavior of the German people as a whole during World War II? Was this ever legislated in any way by any Rabbinic leaders and therefore has some Halachic authority its or is  just something that some people have chosen to do on their own?

Comment: I do not know of any practice like this. What about Jews living in Germany? Besides, the people who live in Germany now are not the people who lived in Nazi Germany. Also, just because the Nazis were anti-Semitic beyond belief and were in power over Germany does not mean every German agreed with their philosophy during WWII.  -1

Comment: Why did this question get 4 negative reps? There are many Jews who do not buy Mercedes cars because of its German make etc. Many Jews who do this are quite Orthodox, despite the fact that many Orthodox Jews oppose such a practice. Why does Mark A. deserve to be negged?? This question seems on topic to the forum and has been asked respectfully. So he wants to know if there is some sort of Halachhic issue? So what?

Comment: Gotta agree with David Kenner here. But for the record, every single family in Boropark and Williamsburg who "don't own a Mercedes because they are made in Germany", have a Bosch mixer sitting in their kitchen and tons and tons of Playmobile in their kids' toyboxes. Just saying.

Comment: @DavidKenner. Thank you. I was wondering the same thing as well. Sometimes I ask a stupid question and deserve the negative reps, but there has to be some more responsibility with this. If u don't like the question, you can just move on. No need to let out your frustration. No worries though. I don't take it personally.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an RFP, as well as being completely bound up in Shoah politics.

Answer (score 2):

It is an accepted idea to not buy any German cars, but I never heard of people not buying all German products.
Anyway I don't think it has any halachic reasoning. It's just as a kind of silent protest of sorts.
And between me and you, I think that if German cars were cheaper then a lot more people would be buying them.

Comment: For example, Bosch is a german company and yet everybody buys them

Comment: Why would it be strictly limited to automobiles manufactured in Germany and not other products? Why is this even a custom? Consider revising your answer to provide more insight on the topic.

Comment: @shmuel It's not only a German company, as a subsidiary of Siemens, it is a Nazi company that built itself on concentration camp slave labor, was one of the last to "apologize" under duress, and, more recently, was convicted of illicit dealings with Iran. Evil then, evil now. (And I bought the 2nd best rated, American-made dishwasher on Amazon, b/c #1 was a Bosch/Siemens.

Comment: By the way: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haavara_Agreement

Comment: I take it you won’t wear Hugo Boss Suits apparently in a documentary he made suits for the members of the Nazi party. Also I take it you’ll refrain from buying gas/ petrol because we are indirectly funding terrorism? Or the other way round don’t buy computers because some of the technology is made by Israel. It’s a cruel world.